# Add textfield mask swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have textfield and i have text to be in format like XXXXX,XX.
For example, when i print 1, it should output : 0.01
When i print .21 - 0.21
When print 43.21 - 43.21
When print 54321 - 54321 (no dot).

How to achieve that behaviour ? I would prefer to use some kind of private extension to string.

Now i have following in my text field delegate:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        let maxLength = 8
        let currentString: NSString = textField.text! as NSString
        let newString: NSString =
            currentString.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) as NSString
        return newString.length <= maxLength
    }
```

But that code only limits characters count, it does nothing with dots.

Comment: Use a `NumberFormatter` to display the value in the proper format.